# median of medians not working properly

Tags: c, median-of-medians

I'm writing C code for the Median of Medians algorithm to find the kth smallest element in worst case linear time.
I've checked my code for Quick Sort, Swapping, etc.
Everything looks good but still it is not working properly every time.

Input given -

```
n=12 kth=7
A[]=53 22 65 18 89 45 42 63 99 11 36 55
```

Output -

```
Smallest at k=7 is 89
```

but output needs to be

```
Smallest at k=8 is 53
```

Function call -

```
med_of_medians(A,0,n-1,kth);
```

Code -

```
int med_of_medians(int A[], int a, int b, int kth)
{
if(a==b)
    return 0;
int n=(b-a+1),median,pos,rank;
int i,med[(n+4)/5];
for(i=0;i<n/5;i++)
    med[i]=find_median(A,(i*5)+a,((i+1)*5)-1);
if(n%5>0)
    med[i++]=find_median(A,(n/5)*5+a,b);
median=(i==1)?med[0]:find_median(med,0,i-1);
pos=partition(A,a,b,median);
rank=pos-a+1;   
if(rank==kth)
    return A[pos];
else if(rank>kth)
    return med_of_medians(A,a,pos-1,kth);
else
    return med_of_medians(A,pos+1,b,kth-pos-1);
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer by one more fix: `a` should be also added for the new rank in recursive `med_of_medians` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to return `A[a]` in the first `if`:

```
if (a == b)
    return A[a];
```

There is missing `a` in the second index in the `find_median` call:

```
med[i]=find_median(A,(i*5)+a, a +((i+1)*5)-1);
```

and also `a` should be added for the new rank calculation (it should be `kth - rank`):

```
return med_of_medians(A,pos+1,b,kth-pos-1 +  a);
```

Comment: Should be `return A[a];`  0 might not be in the range.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the last one by changing it to `return med_of_medians(A,pos+1,b,kth-rank);`